# Java function error inside jsp

Tags: java, class, jsp

I want  to call Java function from inside the .jsp page in dynamic web application working on tomcat 7. But it gives me error:

JSP CODE:

```
<%
  if(request.getParameter("submit") != null)
   {
  Test t= new Test();
  t.printHello();
    }
  %>


public class Test {

    public void printHello()
    {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }

}
```

and i get ,

> ```
>  ERROR:
>
>
>         An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /NewFile.jsp
>         Test cannot be resolved to a type
>             14:    <%
>             15:   if(request.getParameter("submit") != null)
>             16:    {
>             17:   Test t= new Test();
>             18:   t.printHello();
>             19:     }
>             20:   %>
> ```

Comment: have you imported the class `Test` in your jsp

Comment: Try to avoid scriplet.

Comment: U need to import that class into the jsp have u done it?

Comment: After importing now this error:

Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The import com.jsp.Test cannot be 
  resolved
 - The import com.jsp.Test cannot be 
  resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If seems that `Test` has not been imported in the jsp.

Add this in the top of your jsp file to import the Test class

```
<%@page import="package.location.Test" %>
```

**EDIT**

*[Braj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25152369/3176651) is the best way to use Java code in JSP files (JSTL, EL). Take a good look at the links and tutorials included there.*

Comment: Now I'm getting this error on jsp page.Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The import com.jsp.Test cannot be 
  resolved
 - The import com.jsp.Test cannot be 
  resolved

Comment: You need to add the package of the Test class. is it actually inside the `com.jsp` package. You can see the package above your class. @user1540371

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to avoid Scriplet and use [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) and [Expression language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).

```
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="com.x.y.z.Test"/>
${test.printHello()}
```

Either import the class or use fully qualified name of the class.

Have a look at [General JSP Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14014/genlovw.htm)

Comment: +1 This should be the answer, discouraging the use of scriptlets

Comment: Pointed to your answer, which is actually the better one. :)